# Password for ssh

Tags: ssh

Hey guys am realy new in ubuntu. am trying to connect my machine to one of the remote system.
Both are running on ubuntu operating system.

I have tried connecting to the remote system like

```
ssh remote_username@ip_of_machine_am_connecting
```

When i run this on terminal it asks for the password

At this section which password i wanna enter ??

Is it the password of the remote machine to which am connecting to ??

Any help or advices  would be great..Thanx

Comment: Have you tried them both before asking? ;-) It's the password on the remote machine. If you do just `ssh ip_of_remote_machine` it will try to use your local username on the remote machine.

Comment: See http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/SSH_overview or tips (those ssh pages are from my LUG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you will have to enter the remote password. If not, there wouldn't be any sense about passwords.

Assume your user name is bill, and the other one's user is steve. Bill's password is not relevant here, steve's password is 1234, the host's ip is 10.0.0.25

Now you run

```
ssh steve@10.0.0.25
```

Now it will ask you for a password, which is 1234.

Comment: Just a comment on "there wouldn't be any sense about passwords" -  You can connect to a ssh server without password authentication, and, if you are using keys, you would enter the password associated with the key.

Comment: There are several ways to authorize, but using your local password in order to authorize on a remote machine, makes no sense.